# How to find min float value in multiple array if one of element quil zero

Tags: php

Here is my multiple array

```
Array
(
    [3432] => Array
        (
            [2] => 7.2
            [3] => 1.5
            [4] => 2.1
        )

    [11350] => Array
        (
            [2] => 23.168
            [3] => 4.344
            [4] => 4.344
        )

    [12175] => Array
        (
            [2] => 8.112
            [3] => 6.288
            [4] => 4.344
        )

    [12306] => Array
        (
            [2] => 9.036
            [3] => 0.9
            [4] => 0
        )

)
```

and i need to find a min sum value.
When i use php min function i get 10.8

```
Array
(
    [2] => 7.2
    [3] => 1.5
    [4] => 2.1
)

10.8
```

but the minimun of all array is 9.936

```
[12306] => Array
        (
            [2] => 9.036
            [3] => 0.9
            [4] => 0
        )
```

Comment: `min(array_map('array_sum', $yourArray)); // (float) 9.936` - http://codepad.viper-7.com/SPuljy

Comment: 10x for help @billyonecan

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?php
$input = array(
    11350 => array(
        2 => 23.168,
        3 => 4.344,
        4 => 4.344,
    ),
    12175 => array(
        2 => 8.112,
        3 => 6.288,
        4 => 4.344,
    ),
    12306 => array(
        2 => 9.036,
        3 => 0.9,
        4 => 0,
    ),
);

$sums = array();
foreach ($input as $row) {
    $sums[] = array_sum($row);
}

print_r(min($sums));
```

**EDIT**

or more PHP way:

```
print_r(min(array_map('array_sum', $input)));
```